# Mejorar Performance Foreachs Anidados

Tags: c#, rendimiento, iteraciones

Tengo 2 `foreach` anidados de una clase artículos, en la que  recorro dos listas, y si el elemento de la lista 1 se encuentra en la lista 2, debe hacer un par de operaciones, el dilema es que al tratarse de listas muy largas, se demora mucho y necesito mejorar ese tiempo.

**Código:**

```
foreach (Articulo x in Articulos) //Lista Principal
{
  foreach(Articulo y in listSec)
  {
    if (y.Art_CodGen == x.Art_CodGen) //Si son Iguales 
    {
      if (y.Precios[0] != x.Precios[i]) //Y tienen distinto precio
      {
        updatedRows += UpdateArticulo(x, i); // Actualizo
      }
    }
   }                                                                         
 }
```

Comment: Iba a darte una respuesta, pero no entiendo que es `i` en tu código cuando comparas precios: `y.Precios[0] != x.Precios[i]`. Puedes aclararlo?

Comment: Pikoh! , la i es simplemente un indice de una iteración anterior que necesito mandarle al update, no influye en éste bloque

Comment: Ya entiendo. De todas maneras mi respuesta iba en la linea de la de @miguel, asi que yo probaría algo asi

Comment: varias preguntas.. las listas estan ordenadas? se puede usar linq para algunas cosas? hay algun tipo de restriccion? como se arman las listas? de que tipo son esas listas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El detalle que veo en tu código es que por cada **item** en la lista 1 estas recorriendo **completamente** la lista 2, por que tu **if** lo que hace es identificar que sean iguales en el Art_CodGen y que sean de distinto precio, para finalmente actualizar, esto no detiene el foreach de la lista 2 y sigue iterando objetos así como también sigue evaluando y afectando el performance de la aplicación. Te dejare el fragmento de código que ocupo en estos casos y te lo explico detalladamente mas abajo:

```
  foreach (persona pItem in lista1)
            {
                persona perAux = lista2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Codigo == pItem.Codigo);

                if (perAux != null)
                {
                    //Actualizas
                    Console.WriteLine("La persona: " + perAux.Nombre + " esta en la lista dos");
                }
            }
```

Ahora te explico el escenario que monte, he definido un objeto de tipo persona con dos atributos, ya sabes para simplificar las cosas:

```
 public class persona
        {
            public int Codigo { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
        }
```

Se crean dos listas de tipo persona:

```
 List<persona> lista1 = new List<persona>();
 List<persona> lista2 = new List<persona>();
```

Se añaden objetos a las lista donde, **ojo** tres de las personas estarán en ambas listas (`Katz , Manuel y Uriel`).

```
//Personas que iran en la lista 1
            persona p1 = new persona() { Codigo = 1,Nombre="Katz" };
            persona p2 = new persona() { Codigo = 2, Nombre = "Katz" };
            persona p3 = new persona() { Codigo = 3, Nombre = "Arturo" };
            persona p4 = new persona() { Codigo = 4, Nombre = "Moises" };
            persona p5 = new persona() { Codigo = 5, Nombre = "Manuel" };
            persona p6 = new persona() { Codigo = 6, Nombre = "Uriel" };

            lista1.Add(p1);
            lista1.Add(p2);
            lista1.Add(p3);
            lista1.Add(p4);
            lista1.Add(p5);
            lista1.Add(p6);

            //Personas que iran en la lista 2
            persona p7 = new persona() { Codigo = 1, Nombre = "Katz" };
            persona p8 = new persona() { Codigo = 5, Nombre = "Manuel" };
            persona p9 = new persona() { Codigo = 6, Nombre = "Uriel" };
            persona p10 = new persona() { Codigo = 7, Nombre = "Ana" };
            persona p11 = new persona() { Codigo = 8, Nombre = "Rosa" };
            persona p12 = new persona() { Codigo = 9, Nombre = "Luisa" };

            lista2.Add(p7);
            lista2.Add(p8);
            lista2.Add(p9);
            lista2.Add(p10);
            lista2.Add(p11);
            lista2.Add(p12);
```

Ya definido el escenario ahora si te explico el código, se realiza un único foreach que recorre los objetos de tipo persona en la primera lista, dentro del foreach de la primera lista se crea un objeto persona auxiliar, ahora esta es la parte donde debes prestar atención:

```
lista2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Codigo == pItem.Codigo);
```

Se realiza una búsqueda utilizando la función `FirstOrDegault` y una expresión lambda (muy útiles) donde se evalúa que el codigo (ID) del objeto pItem de la lista 1 se encuentre en la lista dos:

```
x => x.Codigo == pItem.Codigo
```

**si encuentra a alguien igual en la lista 2 el objeto perAux no sera nulo**  y bueno también puedes hacer tu otro if (el de los precios), por que el objeto **perAux** es el que extrajiste de la **lista 2** y el **pItem** es el de la **lista 1** es decir tienes los **dos objetos para hacer la lógica que requieras**.

```
 foreach (persona pItem in lista1)
                {
                    persona perAux = lista2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Codigo == pItem.Codigo);

                    if (perAux != null)
                    {
                        //Actualizas
                        Console.WriteLine("La persona: " + perAux.Nombre + " esta en la lista dos");
                    }
                }
```

Esta es la salida del programa.

```
La persona: Katz esta en la lista dos
La persona: Manuel esta en la lista dos
La persona: Uriel esta en la lista dos
```

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres mejorar el rendimiento puedes usar `Thread` o `ForEach` asíncronos para si recorrerlos más rápidamente. Un amanera de implementar este funcionamiento sería con la función `Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body);`

Además en la segunda búsqueda podrías usar `Linq` para solo buscar los que necesitas recorrer( aunque al fin y al cabo es una búsqueda pero más optimizada).

Un ejemplo de la implementación de esta solución sería algo así:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Articulos, RecorrerSegunda);

public void RecorrerSegunda(Articulo art)
{
        var articulos = listSec.Where(c => c.Art_CodGen == art.Art_CodGen && c.Precios[0] == art.Precios[i]);
        Parallel.ForEach(articulos, new Action<Articulo>(
            (a) =>
            {
                lock(art)
                {
                    UpdateArticulo(art, i);
                }
            }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar la búsqueda binaria. Te explico la idea:

- divides el conjunto en 2 subconjuntos,
- buscas en cada uno de los 2 subconjuntos,
- verificas comparando si es menor o mayor,
- mediante a esa comparación eliges un subconjunto,
- con el nuevo subconjunto, vuelves a dividir en 2 subconjuntos, y vas repitiendo el algoritmo.

**Ventajas:**

Siempre vas dividiendo el conjunto y eliges el conjunto en el que seguramente puede estar tu objeto.

**Ejemplo:**

- buscado: `5`
- conjunto `{12,5, 1 , 4, 49, 89}`
- ordenando `5      {1,4,5,12,49,89}`
- `5   {1,4,5}{12,49,89}`
- 1 es menor que 5, por lo tanto 5 puede que sí
- este en el 1er subconjunto, 49 es el primer elemento del segundo conjunto, y 49 es mayor que 5 por lo tanto 5 no se encuentra en el segundo subconjunto.

  ---
- segunda iteracion {1,4,5}

  - y así sucesivamente...

Comment: Pregunto: si tuviese que hacer una búsqueda binaria pero mis listas no poseen solo datos numéricos el procedimiento en el mismo?

Comment: @AgustinM. si se aplica a todo aquel que sea comparable, no suelo programar en c# pero en java hay una clase Comparable